# Cauchy Problem: $x_1\partial_1u(x)+x_2\partial_2u(x)+x_1x_2u(x)=0$ with initial conditions: $\Omega = (0,\infty)^2,\: x\in \Omega;\: u(q,q^2)=5, q>0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega := (0,\infty)^2$.

Solve
\begin{align*}
x_1\partial_1u(x)+x_2\partial_2u(x)+x_1x_2u(x)=0,\quad x\in \Omega
\end{align*}

with initial conditions: $u(q,q^2)=5,\quad q>0$.

Show the solution is:
\begin{align*}
u(x)=5\exp\left\{\dfrac{-(x_1x_2-x^3_2/x_1^3)}{2}\right\}
\end{align*}

Before evaluating the Cauchy Problem I have a question about $\Omega$, what does it mean that $\Omega := (0,\infty)^2$? The $(0,\infty)$ could be interpreted as any real number above $0$, but the $2$ in the superscript throws me a bit off, is it an indication of the dimension of $\Omega$ such that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$? If so, I read it as equivalent to $x_1,x_2\in(0,\infty)$.

1. As for the solution in question lets define
   \begin{align*}
       u'(x) = \begin{bmatrix} \partial_1 u(x) & \partial_2 u(x)
       \end{bmatrix}, \quad \quad
       A= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix},\quad \quad
       b= x_1 x_2, \quad \quad
       f=0
   \end{align*}
2. Now lets find the flow, define
   \begin{align*}
       \varphi ' (t) := A\quad \text{thus} \quad \varphi (0) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}.
   \end{align*}
   Now we find $\varphi(t)$ by integrating each of the entries and the constants are $x_1,x_2$ respectively, such that
   \begin{align*}
       \varphi(t) = \begin{bmatrix} tx_1 + x_1\\ tx_2 + x_2 \end{bmatrix}
   \end{align*}
   This is the flow we then define, $\Phi(t,x)=\varphi(t)$.
3. Now define $X(t,q):=\Phi(t,\gamma(q))$, where $\gamma(q)=\begin{bmatrix} q \\ q^2\end{bmatrix}$, and now we substitute $x_1=q$, $x_2=q^2$ such that
   \begin{align*}
       X(t,q)=\begin{bmatrix}tq+q \\ tq^{2}+q^2\end{bmatrix}
   \end{align*}
   Now set
   \begin{align*}
      \begin{bmatrix}tq+q \\ tq^{2}+q^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}
   \end{align*}
   Now isolate $q$ such that
   \begin{align*}
       x_1=tq+q=q(t+1)\\
       q=\frac{x_1}{t+1}
   \end{align*}
   Insert $q$ into the second equation and isolate for $t$
   \begin{align*}
        x_2&=tq^{2}+q^2=q^2(t+1)\\
        x_2&=\Big(\frac{x_1}{t+1} \Big)^2(t+1)\\
        x_2&=\frac{x_1^2}{t+1}\\
        tx_2+x_2&=x_1^2\\
        t&=\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}-1
   \end{align*}
4. Now we use the theorem for finding solutions to non-characteristic Cauchy Problems:
   \begin{align*}
   Z(t,q):&=\phi(\gamma(q))e^{-\int_0^tb(X(s,q))ds}+\int_0^te^{-\int_0^tb(X(r,q))dr}f(X(s,q))ds\\
   \end{align*}
   Here $\phi(\gamma(q))=u(q,q^2)=5$, $b(X(s,q))=b=x_1x_2$, and $f(X(s,q))=f=0$ such that
   \begin{align*}
   Z(t,q)&=5e^{-\int_0^tx_1x_2ds}+0,\\
   &=5e^{-tx_1x_2},\\
   &=5e^{-(\frac{x_1^2}{x_2}-1)x_1x_2},\\
   &=5e^{(1-\frac{x_1^2}{x_2})x_1x_2},\\
   &=5e^{x_1x_2-x_1^3}.
   \end{align*}

As you can see this solution is not the same as stated in the beginning.
Where did it go wrong?

Comment: First, $(0,\infty)^2$ denotes the Cartesian product of $(0,\infty)$. That is, it’s the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}$. But that’s equivalent to your formulation. Second, it looks like the problem simplifies greatly if you change coordinates to $v:=\ln u$ and similarly for $x_1,x_2$.

Comment: It would have been much easier to simply solve the system $$\frac{d_{1}}{x_{1}} = \frac{d_{2}}{x_{2}} = \frac{d_{u}}{-x_{1} x_{2} u}$$ Also, in this form, it is (hopefully) obvious why the change of coordinates Semiclassical suggested is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve the problem following Matthew Cassell's sugestion. The [Lagrange-Charpit equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) for the PDE
$$
x_1\partial_1u+x_2\partial_2u+x_1x_2u=0 \tag{1}
$$
are
$$
\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{dx_2}{x_2}=\frac{du}{-x_1x_2u}. \tag{2}
$$
Solving the first equality, we obtain
$$
x_2=C_1x_1,\quad\text{or}\quad \frac{x_2}{x_1}=C_1. \tag{3}
$$
Combining the first two terms of $(2)$, we obtain another separable equation:
$$
\frac{x_2dx_1+x_1dx_2}{x_2x_1+x_1x_2}=-\frac{du}{x_1x_2u} \implies
\frac{d(x_1x_2)}{2}=-\frac{du}{u} 
$$
$$
\implies u=C_2\exp\left(-\frac{x_1x_2}{2}\right). \tag{4}
$$
It follows from $(3)$ and $(4)$ that the general solution to $(1)$ is
$$
u(x_1,x_2)=f\!\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{x_1x_2}{2}\right). \tag{5}
$$
The function $f$ is determined by the condition $u(q,q^2)=5$:
$$
f\!\left(\frac{q^2}{q}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{q^3}{2}\right)=5
\implies f(q)=5\exp\left(\frac{q^3}{2}\right), \tag{6}
$$
hence
$$
u(x_1,x_2)=5\exp\left(\frac{-x_1x_2+(x_2/x_1)^3}{2}\right). \tag{7}
$$